# REST API - more parameters for convenience

Tags: rest, api

Lets suppose you use some NoSQL database ( like Cassandra ) what puts some limitation on your queries.

Suppose we have an endpoint /bucket. Due to database schema we need both: user id ( the owner of the bucket ) and bucket id to get it.

Will you introduce one parameter ( bucket id ) to the endpoint ( and have to make 2 queries ) or 2 parameters ( bucket id, user id ) and then you can get it with 1 query?

Best regards

Comment: A REST architecture doesn't care how your URI is build. The API will provide all the URIs a client may choose from in a response and the client will determine whether to invoke the URI based on a meaningful link relation name. In general though it is preferable to minimize the queries if possible. In best case client-side and/or intermediary caching may prevent the request from reaching the server at all. It is therefore primarily opinionated how you design your API